# Importing fastai.imports in PyCharm works when running the file, but not in Python Console

Tags: python, pycharm, fast-ai

Running `from fastai.imports import *` works in a normal terminal and from the "Run"-tab in PyCharm, but returns a hailstorm of error messages when executed in the "Python Console" window.

The amount of error messages is so big that it forces the console to quit the process with the error code -1073740791 (0xC0000409).

When typing, PyCharm autocompletes the import statement correctly, suggesting the `.imports`-ending after `fastai`.

Any idea to how I can fix it?

Comment: Can you check that the Python interpreter of the project is the same as the Python interpreter for the Console?
Go to `File > Settings > Project > Project interpreter` to see the interpreter used when running the file. Then go to `File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Console > Python Console`: if the interpreter is different there, change it. You can also try to tick in the two boxes about the `PYTHONPATH`.
Finally, as a safety measure, do `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart`.